# moving a button vertically (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am making a wac a mole game in swift and need to know how to make a button (Mole image) move up and down popping out and back into its hole (Above and back behind a imageview).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the button's frame to incrementally move up and down with animation. Here is some sample code (`yAxisMovement` is a positive number to move the button up or a negative number to move the image down):

```
var duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: { () -> Void in
    button.frame = CGRectMake(
        button.frame.origin.x,
        button.frame.origin.y - yAxisMovement,
        button.frame.size.width,
        button.frame.size.height)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer above doesn't work anymore due to deprecated methods

```
let duration: TimeInterval = 1.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            self.yourImage.frame.origin.y = -50
            }, completion: nil)
```

use -50 to make it move downwards and 50 to make it move upwards